# No syntax highlighting for C++ in Atmel Studio

Tags: atmelstudio

I just downloaded Atmel Studio 7 to program ATMegas and I'm using C++ (not C) for that.

Unfortunately, there's no syntax coloring for C++ - so `namespace`, `class`, `public`, `private` and so on are in regular color (no key words).

Do you know to to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If your file's extension is .cpp, Atmel Studio should correctly color C++ keywords automatically. If it is a .c file, C++ keywords won't be colored. If you change the file's extension you may need to reload the file for Atmel Studio to correctly color the keywords. Make sure your files have a proper extension.

Comment: That's not it. Files of course have *.cpp extension.